# Json_encode giving unvalid JSON

Tags: php, json

I have some code thats suposed to return some info in JSON format.

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    
    include_once '../../config/database.php';
    include_once '../../class/inventory.php';

    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    $items = new Inventory($db);

    $stmt = $items->getInventory();
    $itemCount = $stmt->rowCount();


    echo json_encode($itemCount);

    if($itemCount > 0){
        
        $inventory = array();
        $inventory["body"] = array();
        $inventory["itemCount"] = $itemCount;

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);
            $e = array(
                "id"         => $invId,
                "uid"        => $invUid,
                "name"       => $invName,
                "created" => $invCreated,
                "location" => $invLocation,
                "status"     => $invStatus,
                "weight"       => $invWeight,
                "size"  => $invSize,
                "content"    => $invContent,
                "image"      => $invImage,
                "comment"  => $invComment
            );

            array_push($inventory["body"], $e);
        }
     
        echo json_encode($inventory);
    }

    else{
        http_response_code(404);
        echo json_encode(
            array("message" => "No record found.")
        );
    }
?>
```

But it returns the info with a number appended to the front, making it invalid JSON.

```
3{"body":[{"id":"2","uid":"100002","name":"Telt","created":"2020-12-06 16:53:08","location":"Huset","status":"","weight":"10","size":"NULL","content":"","image":"","comment":"Test"},{"id":"3","uid":"100003","name":"Kano","created":"2020-12-06 17:28:48","location":null,"status":"{\"status\":\"I\",\"user\":\"root\",\"timeStamp\":\"NULL\"}","weight":null,"size":"{\"dimentions\":{\"x\":\"0\", \"y\":\"0\", \"z\":\"0\", \"r\":\"0\"}, \"volume\":\"0\", \"properties\":{\"cube\":\"true\", \"ball\":\"false\", \"cylinder\":\"false\"}}","content":"{\"content\":[{\"invId\":\"NULL\", \"number\":\"0\"}], \"totalWeight\":\"0\"}","image":"\/assets\/images\/default.png","comment":null},{"id":"4","uid":"100004","name":"idk","created":"2020-12-06 17:54:58","location":null,"status":"{\"status\":\"I\",\"user\":\"root\",\"timeStamp\":\"NULL\"}","weight":null,"size":"{\"dimentions\":{\"x\":\"0\", \"y\":\"0\", \"z\":\"0\", \"r\":\"0\"}, \"volume\":\"0\", \"properties\":{\"cube\":\"true\", \"ball\":\"false\", \"cylinder\":\"false\"}}","content":"{\"content\":[{\"invId\":\"NULL\", \"number\":\"0\"}], \"totalWeight\":\"0\"}","image":"\/assets\/images\/default.png","comment":null}],"itemCount":3}
```

The number added to the front Is equal to the "itemCount", but I cant figure out where its added to the front.

Comment: `echo json_encode($itemCount);` before your if should be removed.

Comment: @El_Vanja ahhh thanks, i didnt even notice lol

Comment: Ouf why do so many people feel the need to downvote my perfectly valid question

Answer (score 0):

You are printing json twice. First with this echo json_encode($itemCount). And 3 comes from there.